# How to stop overflow of card content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement responsive card as i am beginner to web development i have lost my shape some where in above code my content in the card in small size screen getting over flow as shown below.

```css
#services-card {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 7% 15%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
.card {
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.services-list {
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}
.services-cards-para {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.card-back {
    background-color: #55F007;
    width: 550px;
    height: 70px;
    
}
.card-white {
    width: 550px;
    height: 70px;
}
.card-back:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e60073;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px red;
}
.card-white:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e60073;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px red;
}
@media(min-width: 750px) {
    .card-back, .card-white {
        width: auto;
        font-size: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .inner {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="services-card">
        <h2>Our Services</h2>
        <p class="services-cards-para">Simple and affordable price plans for you.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card border-0">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="services-list p-0">
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-back"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> GST</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Income Tax</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 card-back pt-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> TDS Returns</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Food License (FSSAI)</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 card-back pt-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Labour License</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Trade License</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 card-back pt-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Digital signature</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card border-0">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="services-list p-0">
                            <li class="card-back pt-2 pl-3"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5">Import Export Code</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> PAN / TAN</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 card-back pt-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> Firm Registration</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5">Company / LLP Incorporation</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 card-back pt-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> PF & ESI</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-white"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> MSME / Udyam Regn</span></li>
                            <li class="pl-3 pt-2 card-back"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i><span class="pl-5"> DIN</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwoxB.png)

I am expecting that all the content should limit to the background in all sizes of screen can some one please drive me to get the accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

from the code you sent I can guess that you are using bootstrap , you can go to this link to see how to use it: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_large.asp